# Network is unreachable

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I'm a bit lost trying to solve this one.

This is a machine coming up on Google Compute Engine.

It says "Network is unreachable" when I try to access the network.

The network appears to be functioning because eth0 has a network address which it got from the Google DHCP server. Below is the output of "ifconfig" and "route"

Google says that the network this machine is on is 10.240.0.0/16 with a gateway at 10.240.0.1

Output of route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
127.0.0.1       *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 lo
```

Output of ifconfig -a

```
dummy0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 72:E6:19:7F:A1:8E  
          BROADCAST NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:01:0A:F0:00:02  
          inet addr:10.240.0.2  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1102 (1.0 KiB)  TX bytes:342 (342.0 B)

ip_vti0   Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-FF-FF-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          NOARP  MTU:1364  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tunl0     Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

```
sleep 10 (not sure if this line matters but it seems the system needs a few seconds for something to complete?)
sudo udhcpc
sudo route add -net 10.240.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev eth0
sudo route add default gw 10.240.0.1 eth0
```